# PsiTreeVisitor: How to find out type of KtCallExpression receiver?

Tags: kotlin

When parsing a Kotlin file with the `PsiTreeVisitor` how do I find out the fully qualified type of a KtCallExpression?

As an example:

```
fun test() {
    (1..10).forEach {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

From this code I want to figure out if the `forEach` method is being called on an `IntRange` object

By using the `visitCallExpression` function I can figure out the method receiver (`(1..10)` in this case). But so far I haven't found a way to determine the package and type of the receiver correctly.

Comment: the `(1..10).forEach` expression is  consist with two expressions `1..10`  and `forEach`. it evaluate the left expression to obtain the `receiver` , and then evaulate `forEach` expression.

Comment: @holi-java Yep, I am able to get the receiver but how do I then find out the full type of the receiver?

Comment: are you mean you want to fetch the `receiver` class?

Comment: Yes, in the example above I want to find out if the `(1..10)` receiver is of type `IntRange`

Comment: you can obtain the `receiver` type from `context` in this visitor method: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/a8f1e32dec0782eab3d52ce682572d6f7d6fd07b/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/types/expressions/BasicExpressionTypingVisitor.java#L707

Answer (score 0):

To get the type information, you need to *resolve* the identifier of the caller, which requires a [`BindingContext`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/resolve/BindingContext.java). The caller is the first child of a `KtDotQualifiedExpression`.

```
override fun visitCallExpression(expression: KtCallExpression) {
    val caller = (expression.parent as? KtDotQualifiedExpression)?.firstChild as? KtElement
    val type = caller.getResolvedCall(bindingContext)?.resultingDescriptor?.returnType

    // `type` will be `IntRange` in your case.
}
```

Comment: But, how to get bindingContext? @steven